# Amplitude in Standing Waves Equation

Tags: waves, wavefunction

Why in standing waves equation $y(x,t)=Asin(kx)cos(ωt)$ ,the amplitude term is said to be $Asin(kx) $?

Why can't it  just be  $A$ ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at a standing wave, the amplitude of vibration is different at different places.

$A$ is the maximum amplitude anywhere in the wave

$A \sin (kx)$ is the maximum amplitude at position $x$.